# MS Teams outgoing webhook response

Tags: microsoft-teams

I create a Bot to sent a request with outgoing webhook,
Now i just want to get the text from the json and do not response any thing. So in my falsk app I return Response(status=200)

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/" , methods=['POST'])
def hello():

    # wget webhook post message
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())

    return Response(status=200)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But in the Teams channel still show the message
'Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elton Wang It is mandatory to send a message from outgoing webhook to MS Teams. You cannot send a empty message body.

Comment: i just want to repsonse the message with incoming webhook! but thank you for the information.